# Is it possible to update Firebase CloudFirestore from flutter withouth authenticating a user?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I set up these permissions for debugging purposes on my Firestore.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a new document in the collection after I upload the image, but I get an error.

This is my flutter code

```
  StorageUploadTask putFile =
      storage.ref().child("region/$fileName").putFile(_regionImage);

  UploadTaskSnapshot uploadSnapshot = await putFile.future;

  print("image uploaded");

  var regionData = new Map();
  regionData["label"] = _textController.text;

  var pictureData = new Map();
  pictureData["url"] = uploadSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString();
  pictureData["storage"] = "gs://app-db.appspot.com/region/$fileName";
  regionData["picture"] = pictureData;

  DocumentReference currentRegion =
      Firestore.instance.collection("region").document(fileName);

  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DocumentSnapshot freshSnap = await transaction.get(currentRegion);
    print(freshSnap.exists);
    await transaction.set(currentRegion, regionData);
    print("instance created");
  });
```

This is my console log
https://gist.github.com/matejthetree/c34d0dcba507acd511773ae9b14a8725

I followed the new [Google Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase) and uploading and getting the images from storage is working, also getting the collection data that I created from the firebase console is also working.

Example of working collection retrieval:

```
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("region").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
      return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
          var imageUrl = ds["picture"]["url"];
          var imageLabel = ds["label"];
          var imageCard = new RegionCard(imageUrl, imageLabel);
          return imageCard;
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

How to approach creating new documents in the collection?

As @gunter said in comments, having public write permissions was very bad, so I decided to try sign-in approach.

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298205/firebase-uploading-files-anonymously-without-authentication (no good answer though)

Comment: I guess you are aware that this way malicious people can use your storage to share copyrighted material like videos which could become quite expensive to you (Google fees and copyright infringement).

Comment: Didn't have that in mind.I am making an app for demo purposes, so I was wandering what is the easiest way to write to collections, without going trough some kind of authentication.

Comment: Maybe a new question

Comment: Thank you, I will try different approach tomorrow.